# Python list reading integers

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I am trying to create a simple script that should count how many `integers` or `strings` there are in a list.
At first the list is empty, then the user is asked to fill it with numbers or strings, this is the script:

```
lis = []            # list name

num, lett = 0, 0    # init counters of numbers and letters
while True:
   x = input("digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values: ")
   if(x=='stop'):
      False
      break

   i = lis.append(x)
   if isinstance(i, int): # check whether is integer
       num += 1
   else:
       lett += 1    

print(lis)
print("there are " + str(num) + " numbers")
print("there are " + str(lett) + " strings")
```

The program works, but the problem comes in the end, because when I print the list, it sees only strings, even numbers are returned as '10', for example.

I need the interpreter to automatically recognise integers.

Comment: You need to use `x.isdigit()`, since `x` is still a string `isinstance()` will fail every time because it tests the data type of the variable not the _character content_. But there are many, _many_ more mistakes in your code besides this one. I suggest going over a tutorial for Python to get an idea of how to program in it.

Comment: ``The program works`` I highly doubt that. ``lis.append(x)`` returns ``None``. Btw: the ``False`` before your ``break`` does nothing.

Comment: **to users who are answering**: Please stop answering this question. It is broad, off-topic and will most likely not help any future users. It would benefit the OP much more if he read a begginer tutorial for Python. Simply posting code-dump, after code-dump is not helping anyone. At the every least you could provide an explanation with your code.

Comment: @mpf82 It would work in the sense that he wouldn't get an error. `lis.append(x)` returning `None` just compounds the issue with checking if `i` is of type `int` -- `i` will never be an `int`, for it is `None`, and thus his code calls it a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lis = []            # list name

num, lett = 0, 0    # init counters of numbers and letters
while True:
  x = input("digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values: ")
  if(x=='stop'):
    break
  if x.isdigit():
    lis.append(int(x))
    num += 1
  elif x.isalpha(): 
    lis.append(x)
    lett += 1

print(lis)
print("there are " + str(num) + " numbers")
print("there are " + str(lett) + " strings")
```

**Result**

```
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  1
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  2
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  3
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  a
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  b
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  c
digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values:  stop
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
there are 3 numbers
there are 3 strings
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = l = 0
res = []
while True:
    s = input("input string or digit\n")
    if s == 'exit':
        break

    ## this is one way, might be faster to do it using isdigit suggested in the comment
    try:            
        temp = int(s)
        d += 1
    except ValueError:
        l += 1
    res.append(s)

print(d)
print(l)
print(res)
```

Comment: Using a bare `exception` clause is considered bad practice. Use a specific exception instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the return value of `list.append` is an integer, which is not. Therefore, it counts it as a string.

```
lis = []            # list name

num, lett = 0, 0    # init counters of numbers and letters
while True:
   x = input("digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values: ")
   lis.append(x)
   if(x=='stop'):
      break

for items in lis:
    if items.isdigit(): # check whether is integer
        num += 1
    else:
        lett += 1   

print(lis)
print("there are " + str(num) + " numbers")
print("there are " + str(lett) + " strings")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution that works on my Python IDLE version 3.6.0 (Please reply if it doesn't work for you):

```
lis = []            # list name

num, lett = 0, 0    # init counters of numbers and letters

while True:
    try:
        x = input("digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values: ")
        i = lis.append(x)
        if(x=='stop'):
            False
            break   
    except ValueError:
        print("Not an integer!")
        continue
    else:
        num += 1

print(lis)
print("there are " + str(num) + " numbers")
print("there are " + str(lett) + " strings")
```

Comment: At the moment it does not recognise strings, every value is taken as integer because it only increases _num_, even if I write 'eggs'

Answer (score 0):

here's my code

```
while True:
    l,num,lett = [],0,0
    while True:
        x = input('digit an int or string, "stop" returns values: ').lower().strip()
        try:
            x = int(x)
        except:
            pass
        if x == ('stop'):
            break
        l.append(x)

    for element in l:
        if isinstance(element, int):
            num += 1
        else:
            lett += 1

    print (l)
    print ("there are " + str(num) + " numbers")
    print ("there are " + str(lett) + " strings")
    l,num,lett = [],0,0     #reset to go again
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isdigit` and change your code to this:

```
lis = []            # list name

num, lett = 0, 0    # init counters of numbers and letters
while True:
    x = input("digit an int or string, 'stop' returns values: ")
    if(x=='stop'):
      False
      break
    if x.isdigit(): # check whether is integer
        lis.append(int(x))
        num += 1
    else:
        lis.append(x)
        lett += 1   

print(lis)
print("there are " + str(num) + " numbers")
print("there are " + str(lett) + " strings")
```

Also, you can fix your code with this (it need an indented and move it into your main `while`):

```
if isinstance(int(x), int): # check whether is integer
    num += 1
    lis.append(int(x))
else:
    lett += 1
    lis.append(x)
```

Comment: Ok, it does work, thank you. Just one more question: when I print the list, I see this output ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'].
This means that the list is filled with strings, isn't it?
If value1 were an integer, would the output be [value1, 'value2', 'value3'], or not?